# xml.haml template dynamic constant assignment

Tags: ruby, xml, haml

I am trying to produce a xml.haml template but I am receiving a "dynamic constant assignment" error at the `%Worksheet{ss:Name="Sheet1"}`. I have tried many variations but all error.

```
!!! XML
%Workbook{xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet", xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office", xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel", xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadshet", xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"}
%Worksheet{ss:Name="Sheet1"} 
  %Table
    %Row
      %Cell
        %Data{ss:Type="String"}ID
      %Cell
        %Data{ss:Type="String"}Name
      %Cell
        %Data{ss:Type="String"}Release Date
      %Cell
        %Data{ss:Type="String"}Price
  - @addresses.each do |address|
    %Row
      %Cell
        %Data{ss:Type="Number"}= address.id
      %Cell
        %Data{ss:Type="String"}= address.name
      %Cell
        %Data{ss:Type="String"}= address.released_on
      %Cell
        %Data{ss:Type="Number"}= address.price
```

What is the correct way to translate this html?

**Edit**

I changed the style attributes to the HTML style as suggested. Now, it exports the document but it "cannot be opened for some reason". Here is the updated code.

```
!!! XML
%Workbook(xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadshet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40")
%Worksheet(ss:Name="Sheet1")
  %Table
    %Row
      %Cell
        %Data(ss:Type="String")ID
      %Cell
        %Data(ss:Type="String")Name
      %Cell
        %Data(ss:Type="String")Email
      %Cell
        %Data(ss:Type="String")Phone
  - @addresses.each do |address|
    %Row
      %Cell
        %Data(ss:Type="Number")= address.id
      %Cell
        %Data(ss:Type="String")= address.company_name
      %Cell
        %Data(ss:Type="String")= address.email
      %Cell
        %Data(ss:Type="Number")= address.phone
```

Comment: That code doesn’t do what you probably think it does. Check out the docs for [attributes (using `{}`, parsed as Ruby)](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#attributes_) and [HTML style attributes (using `()`)](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#htmlstyle_attributes_).

Comment: Shouldn’t `Worksheet` be inside `Workbook` (you’ve got them at the same level)?